# How to correctly return from function

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, types

How to correctly return apiKey from User.ts createUser function to Test.ts  in my case?

User.ts

```
interface User {
  url: string,
  name: string,

}
```

```
class User{
  async createUser(
   user: User
  ):Promise<void> { 
    let apiKey = await user.getUserApiKey(user.name);
    console.log(`${user.name} api key - ${apiKey} received`);
return apiKey;
    }
}
```

Test.ts

```
test("Smoke Test", async (t) => {
console.log(${apiKey} - User api key)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to specify `Promise<void>` to the correct type of apiKey.
It may look like `Promise<String>`, or leave the return type specification empty (i.e. remove the `: Promise<void>` from the `createUser` method).

In the Test.ts you have to create a User object first and call the `createUser` Method on this object.

```
test("Smoke Test", async (t) => {
    let user = new User();
    user.name = "theName";
    user.url = "theURL";
    let apiKey = await user.createUser(user);
    console.log(${apiKey} - User api key)
}
```

It seems like, the `createUser` method is not well designed. Is it intentional to have a (possible different) `user` parameter, although it is called on a user object?